# SQLServer - Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a value that should be not possible.
I look for help to resolve this.

Airplane Table:

[image]

It should not add this row, because in the AirplaneType table there is no row with ID: 1

AirplaneType Table:

[image]

Relationship:

[image]

## **Sorry:**

I'm sorry guys! Every thing is right! I just forgot to save the relationships -.-'
Really sorry.

Comment: what is the data type of this field

Comment: @A5l-lE5 It's Integer

Comment: and what is your insert query also check if the default value is set to '1'

Comment: @A5l-lE5 It's 1. It should not add add this row. There's no row in AirplaneType table.

Comment: M.ali  has answered right its in edit mode.you might be getting confused ,check for the output of select query.

Answer (score 3):

This is edit mode, a very useless GUI of SSMS to make inserts, deletes and updates in your table, It will allow you to type this in but as soon as you click away from it, it should throw an error.

In this edit mode what ever you type in these column it will allow you to type since its not actually being update as you type but as soon as you click away from this column , it should show a pop up window saying you are violating foreign key constraint.

If you execute the following statement it will throw an error straight away saying violation of foreign key constraint blabla.

```
INSERT INTO  Airplane (Airplane, Airplane_Name, Airplane_Type,
                      Airplane_Manfacture, Airplane_Model, Airplane_Stock)
VALUES (1, 'Airplane', 1, 'redbul', 'RB9', 1)
```